# What is the probability of all 3 children of a family being girls given the first 2 are girls?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A couple has 3 children (considering binary gender).
(a) What is the probability that all are girls if the two elder ones are girls?
(b) What is the probability that the third one is a girl if you don’t have any knowledge
about the first two children?
I got the answer 1/2 for the two parts. Is that correct?
For the first part, I divided the probability of the first two kids being girls and third also being a girl (1 * 1 * 1) with the probability of two elder kids being girls and third either being a girl or boy (1 * 1 * 2)

For the second part i simply divided probability of third child being a girl (2 * 2 * 1) by total number of combinations for 3 kids (2 * 2 * 2)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did you get those values?

Comment: If you're going to make assumptions about binary gender, I'd prefer if you make them explicit.

Comment: If you are tossing a coin 3 times and the first 2 times you got heads, what is the chance you'll get heads the third time? Does it depend on what the other two were?

Comment: Neither answer is correct even if you assume the probability of a child being a girl is $\frac12$ and that each child's gender is independent of the others.  Though one of your suggestions would then be the answer to the other question

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I added the explanations

Comment: @Henry can u please explain how to approach this then?

Comment: You assume that every child can be boy or girl, with equal probability, independently. But the question does not include this condition, Maybe a couple decided to have children until they have a boy.  Then the probability that the last child is a boy is 1.

Comment: With your edit, $\frac12$ looks reasonable for both questions on the probability of the third child being a girl if you assume that this is independent of the genders of the first two children

Comment: @kludg I asked my instructor and he said that we are to assume the gender binary with independence

Comment: @joriki This sort of question is really about sex, not gender.